# How much weight can 14 gauge 3” square tubing support?

Tags: fence, steel, engineering, welding

I’m trying to determine the load that will be subjected to a fence I want to build. The idea is that the posts of the fence will be constructed or 3x3-inch 14 gauge square tubing with stringers sized 1.25x1.25-inch, 14 gauge. I wanted to place the posts between 12 and 16 feet apart, if possible, then tacking hog wire along the length as a trellis.

I’ve tried to find a load calculator to determine the capacity of such a design, but I’m unable to. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I’d greatly appreciate it.

Comment: A 1500 pound bull jumping it can bend it.

Comment: But what about a 1400 pound bull?

Comment: Only a 5 inch bend instead of a 6 inch bend.  That is with it built like a diamond shape instead flat(corners on top and bottom).  That is the 1.25 size, supported at six foot spans.

Comment: What kind of loads are you expecting? Some hog wire shouldn't weigh all that much. Are you asking if your 1.25x1.25 tubing will bow under its own weight at a 12-16' span?

Comment: I’m not really worried about it bowing much under its own weight, but instead the weight of vines that might grow along it. I’m planning for honeysuckle, and it should be reasonable to assume that when fully grown, each panel might weigh easily between 100-200 pounds.